# show that $f(x,y) =2x^2 + 3y$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ by finding a linear function T

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

Here's the question: 
Prove that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined $f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 3y$ is differentiable at $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ by producing a linear function T and show that the appropriate limit is 0.

Here's what I got:

$$ Df(0,0) = \lim \limits_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Vert f(x+h, y+h) - f(x,y) -T(k,h)h \Vert}{||h||} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|| f(h,h) - f(0,0) -T(k,h)h ||}{||h||} = \frac{|| 2h^2 + 3h -T(k,h)h ||}{||h||} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|| h(2h + 3 - T(k,h)) ||}{||h||} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} 2h + 3 - T(k,h) = 0$$

And for the last equality to hold, we need $T(k,h) = 3 + ah$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$

I think I'm close, but I'm confident that something is wrong in the last step, so I figured I would ask for a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong thing about your computation is that you have $T(k,h)h$ instead of $T(k,h)$ and $||h||$ in the denominator instead of $||(h,k)||$. Also, you should have $(x,y)=(0,0)$ in your computation.

A more simple way:

1. heuristics: around 0, the quadratic term is very small compared to any
   linear term: it should not contribute to the differential in $(0,0)$.
2. formal proof:
   Let $T(h,k)=3k$. Then:
   $$
   f(0+h,0+k) - f(0,0) - T(h,k) = 2h^2
   \\
   \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac
   {||f(0+h,0+k) - f(0,0) - T(h,k) ||}{||(h,k)||} =
   \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{2h^2}{||(h,k)||} =0
   $$ 
   hence the differential is $T$.

Comment: Great, thank you! One correction (I think) -- should be $2h^2$, not $3h^2$

Comment: indeeed. thanks!!